# Implementing 'cat' in c - wwwmc? (What's wrong with my code)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fputs

My code works fine in a way. I have two issues with it though. One, at the end of printing the  files to the standard output, it gives me a segmentation fault.

Two, I can't use fputs to print out the data because I get a segmentation fault right away. So to fix it I use puts which prints it fine, but adds a '\n' after every line making the text single line spaced as well as the seg fault at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void concat(char *arg){

    char string[256];
    FILE *fp = fopen(arg, "r");

    while(!feof(fp)){
        fgets(string, 256, fp);
        //fputs(string, fp);
        puts(string);
    }

    fclose(fp);

}

void stdincat(){

    char string[256];   
    while(!feof(stdin)){
        fgets(string, 256, stdin);
        fputs(string, stdout);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char argvalues[256][40];

    if(argv[1] == NULL)
        stdincat();
    else if(argv[1] != NULL){
        int i;

        for(i=1;i<=(argc);i++){
            concat(argv[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `fputs` you have commented out in `concat` is attempting to write to `fp`, which you opened only for reading, so it's no surprise that it won't/doesn't work.

Other than that, your reading loops: `while(!feof(fp)) {` (and similar except from `stdin` instead of `fp`) follow a familiar, widespread anti-pattern -- loops like this don't/won't/can't work correctly. You normally want to read and test for success in the same operation:

```
while(fgets(string, 256, stdin))
    fputs(string, stdout);
```

Edit: I should also mention that I would prefer to avoid the duplication of code in `concat` and `stdincat`. I'd rather pass the `FILE *` to read from as the parameter, so you'd use the same code to read from `stdin` or from other arbitrary files:

```
// Warning: untested code.
// error checking omitted for readability.
void catfile(FILE *file) { 
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
        puts(line);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    int i;
    if (argc == 1)
        catfile(stdin);
    else for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        FILE *infile = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        catfile(infile);
        fclose(infile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, I'd note that if you're just going to copy an entire file, `fgets` probably is *not* the most efficient way to do the job. `fread` may be more suitable. While you're at it, you might as well use binary mode reading and writing as well.

Comment: Thanks! The fgets problem was just blind coding. It's embarrassing that I didn't see that..

Everything works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write on the stream that you opened only for read, you should use stdout for the fputs in the function concat